# How can i check the unique key and value in this array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [2] => 3 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [12] => 32 ) 
       [2] => Array ( [2] => 3 ) 
       [3] => Array ( [24] => 42 ) 
);
```

How can i get the output as unique key value. I need to remove the duplicate values.
I need the o/p like this

```
Array ( 
       [0] => Array ( [2] => 3 ) 
       [1] => Array ( [12] => 32 ) 
       [2] => Array ( [24] => 42 ) 
);
```

Comment: What if there are two different values for the same key?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, what do you class as a duplicate value? The key or the value or both?

Comment: I need to remove the duplicate key and values only

Answer (score 1):

[`array_reduce`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php) is likely designed for this purpose:

```
$a = [ [ 2 => 3 ], [ 3 => 4 ], [ 3 => 15 ], [ 2 => 3 ] ];
array_reduce($a, function($memo, $el) { 
  if(false === array_search($el, $memo)) array_push($memo, $el); 
  return $memo; 
}, array())

#⇒ array(3) {
#  [0] =>
#  array(1) {
#    [2] =>
#    int(3)
#  }
#  [1] =>
#  array(1) {
#    [3] =>
#    int(4)
#  }
#  [2] =>
#  array(1) {
#    [3] =>
#    int(15)
#  }
#}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$array = array(
    array(2 => 3),
    array(12 => 32),
    array(2 => 3),
    array(24 => 32)
);

echo 'before array_unique_multi:' . "\n";
print_r($array);

echo 'after array_unique_multi:' . "\n";
print_r(array_unique_multi($array));

function array_unique_multi($array)
{
    $hashAry = array();
    foreach($array as $k=>$v){
        $hash = md5(serialize($v));
        if(in_array($hash, $hashAry)) unset($array[$k]);
        else $hashAry[]=$hash;
    }
    $array = array_values($array);
    return $array;
}
```

Output:

```
before array_unique_multi:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [12] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [24] => 32
        )

)
after array_unique_multi:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [2] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [12] => 32
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [24] => 32
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Mr.Glambert, i get the result of unique array key values.

Comment: I'm assuming that's what you were looking for?

Answer (score -1):

You can use the function `array_unique`. 
http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-unique.php

```
foreach ($myMultiArray as $index => $doublonArray) {
    $myMultiArray[$index] = array_unique($doublonArray);
}
```

Comment: `array_unique` won't work on multi-dimensional arrays.

Comment: Thanks Mr.Barmar i get the result of unique key and value both count, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Use this. This will store all the different key / value pairs in the new array.

```
$test = array(
    array(2 => 3),
    array(12 => 32),
    array(2 => 3),
    array(24 => 42)
);

$tmpArray = array();
$newArray = array();

foreach ($test as $elements) {
    foreach ($elements as $key => $val) {
        if (!array_key_exists($key, $tmpArray) || $tmpArray[$key] !== $val) {
            $tmpArray[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
}
foreach ($tmpArray as $key => $val) {
    $newArray[] = array($key => $val);
}

var_dump($newArray);
```

Output:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      2 => int 3
  1 => 
    array
      12 => int 32
  2 => 
    array
        24 => int 42
```

Comment: Your code concatenate the multiples arrays in only one at the output. Loose the multi-dimensions.

Comment: Not fixed, will always create "one-entry" arrays. What happens if no duplicated values ? => You will have each values in a single array so destruct the original structure.

Comment: If no duplicate values, the result are same. This was the OP request to remove the duplicates.

Comment: test what happens with your code if you have and array with 2 unique values rows, not only one.

Comment: what my code did is create a tmp array, and check, is there an array key as the subarray key, if not, then do nothing, if there is then check the value, and is the value is the same as the given key. So clear. And then transform back to the desired format. What do you do not understand, or what i do not understand?

Answer (score -1):

```
$check_arr = Array ( 
  [0] => Array ( [13] => 1 )
  [1] => Array ( [13] => 3 ) 
  [2] => Array ( [13] => 1 ) 
  [3] => Array ( [10] => 3 ) 
) ;

print_r(array_unique($check_arr));
```

This my result.

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [13] => 1 ) );
```